# How to fit the content to WebView in Android without enabling zooming?

Tags: android, android-webview, zooming, meta-tags

I tried setting meta tag as shown below in order to make the content fit to webview, it didn't work.

```
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, target-densityDpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no\">
```

But when I set the following webview settings, it is working.

```
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.setInitialScale(1);
```

Now the problem is the webview allowing me to zoom on double tap which I don't want. How can I  avoid this behavior? I also tried setting setSupportZoom(true) in webview settings but still I am able to zoom on double tap. Can anybody please suggest me the solution?